# How to find the most frequent text value in a whole spreadsheet on Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know the code to find the most frequent value in a single column, but I'm trying to figure out the code that lets me find the most frequent value in multiple specific columns.

For example:
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(A2:A17,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A2:A17,A2:A17)),COUNTIF(A2:A17,A2:A17),0)))

^^this formula only allows me to have two arguments for COUNTIF

=INDEX(A2:A6,MODE(MATCH(A2:A6,A2:A6,0)))

^^this one only allows 4 arguments max in the index

I want an equation that'll allow me to find the most frequent text value for 16 specific columns.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2):

**BETTER FORMULA**

You asked for formula `when you have 2 top values with the same frequency`

```
=SORTN(QUERY(FLATTEN(H2:K),
         "select Col1, count(Col1) 
          where Col1 is not null group by Col1 
          order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1) '' ",0),1,1,2,0)
```

[image]

---

First answer

Use only  1 `QUERY` formula

For top value

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(A2:D),
         "select Col1, count(Col1) 
          where Col1 is not null group by Col1 
          order by count(Col1) desc limit 1",0)
```

[image]

For all values

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(A2:D),
         "select Col1, count(Col1) 
          where Col1 is not null group by Col1 
          order by count(Col1) desc limit 1",0)
```

[image]

Comment: How about the situation when you have 2 top values with the same frequency?

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski See BETTER FORMULA

Answer (score 0):

I show it in 2 steps then combine steps together in one formula:
First you flatten table and remove duplicates to get a column of values you check frequency for:

```
unique(flatten(B2:I25))
```

Then for each one you check number of occurences:

```
ArrayFormula(countif($B$2:$I$25,unique(flatten(B2:I25))))
```

Then you have to filter new table and get only rows with highest values:

```
=filter({first , second column};second column = max(second column)
```

Using earlier values:

```
=filter({unique(flatten(B2:I25)),ArrayFormula(countif($B$2:$I$25,unique(flatten(B2:I25))))},ArrayFormula(countif($B$2:$I$25,unique(flatten(B2:I25))))=max(ArrayFormula(countif($B$2:$I$25,unique(flatten(B2:I25))))))
```

My solution is available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gMZDFWOY8qbA1Bhp8rZ_por3Skb0i_qQtlaSlCTKXgM/copy

[image]

If your columns are scattered around your sheet, you should use { } and make a table of them.

Comment: Thank you so so much! Extremely helpful :)))))